# Div wont push next divs content down

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to load content dynamically within a div and push the below div down without overlapping. right now this is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/DqS8t/4/). As you can see the buttons start to overlap and doesnt push the next div down. If I set the

```
.container{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

it seems to work the way I want, but I can't make it work with a fixed height.

Comment: Just something you should know. When you set an element to have a `float`, it is set to `display: block`. Setting `display: inline-block` will have no effect. You probably need a clear fix here.

Comment: You use a lot of floating objects in this html. Try to implement this without using float, it will throw off display:inline-block like crush said, but can also make items overlap.

Comment: As much as i like `inline-block`, it does lack browser support [(see support)](http://caniuse.com/inline-block). It you don't care, go for that. Else, you should continue using `float` but also clear them after the floated element's closing tags. You can use simple `clear:both`, `clear:left` or `clear:right` or you could use the more widely supported [clearfix solution](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved the problem by using display:inline-table instead of display:block. and I also removed alot of the float values in the css like you all suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by removing unnecessary float values and using

```
.case-category{
display:inline-table;
}
```

Instead of using `display:block` or `display:inline-block`.